# Angular Formly: Adding more information to a model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-formly

I've been using [Angular Formly](http://angular-formly.com/#/) to render some forms from the JSON response I get from services, however I have a couple of questions.

1. It is possible to obtain data in a field (*templateOptions.label* for example) to add to the model? Or it is necessary to overwrite *FormlyFormController* from **formly-form.js** and add a function as the existing "attachKey"?
2. You can add a field, say groupLabel to a *fieldGroup*, so as to render a title for the group?

Comment: You can definitely [add a new type](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/custom-types/custom-templates) for the groupLabel and use that, or you could simply use the [`template`](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/field-configuration-object#template-string--function) property. For the obtaining field data  question... it kind of depends on what you're trying to do. You definitely have access to that property, and you can even make a [custom controller](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/field-configuration-object#controller-controller-name-as-string--controller-f). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kentcdodds, I want to render the pair "label: value", for each key in my model.

Answer (score 1):

(moved from comment)

You can definitely [add a new type](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/custom-types/custom-templates) for the groupLabel and use that, or you could simply use the [`template`](http://docs.angular-formly.com/v6.12.0-beta.0/docs/field-configuration-object#template-string--function) property.

For the obtaining field data question... it kind of depends on what you're trying to do. You definitely have access to that property, and you can even make a [custom controller](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/field-configuration-object#controller-controller-name-as-string--controller-f). I would recommend looking at the [Creating Custom Templates](http://docs.angular-formly.com/v6.12.0-beta.0/docs/learn-angular-formly#section--custom-templates-https-egghead-io-lessons-angularjs-angular-formly-custom-templates-pl-7-) lesson in the angular-formly docs and use the `options` property to get access to the field configuration and the `model` property to get access to the model.